# image protection in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, security

i have asp.net application , in one page it is showing one model image if u do right click on image and view image it shows of path where it is stored using image id,so people can see other image also how to avoid this.

Comment: Please learn to use tags correctly. Tags are meant to be a lookup mechanism - a quick search. Nobody was going to click the word "in" to find your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some example code for [using an ASHX file to retrieve DB images](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/5223/using-ashx-files-to-retrieve-db-images/)

```
<%@ webhandler language="C#" class="NWEmpPhotoHandler" %>
using System; 
using System.Web; 
using System.Data; 
using System.Data.SqlClient; 
public class NWEmpPhotoHandler : IHttpHandler 
{ 
    public bool IsReusable { get { return true; } } 

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext ctx) 
    { 
        string id = ctx.Request.QueryString["id"]; 

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(<<INSERT CONNECTION STRING HERE>>); 
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Photo FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeID = @EmpID", con); 
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmpID", id); 

        con.Open(); 
        byte[] pict = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar(); 
        con.Close(); 

        ctx.Response.ContentType = "image/bmp"; 
        ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(pict, 78, pict.Length - 78); 
    } 
}
```

You should be able to adapt it to load the file from disk.

Answer (score 0):

In short: **you can't**. Your client browser needs to know where that image is located, so it can be downloaded and rendered.

But you have an option: you can to place that images into a folder where just authenticated users can access. So, you'll need to build that functionality into your website. Isn't that hard: [Introduction to Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're after is **image hotlinking protection**, also known as [inline-linking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_linking) or deep linking etc.

The general method of achieving this is usually to write your own HTTP Module (or HTTP Handler) that effectively intercepts the request/response pipeline, and when an image is needed to be displayed to the browser, the HTTP handler/module outputs, usually byte-by-byte, the image files contents to the response stream sent from the web server to the client web browser.

Try these resources:

[Stopping hot-linking with IIS and ASP.NET](http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2006/11/10/Stopping-hot_2D00_linking-with-IIS-and-ASP.NET.aspx)

[ASP.Net HTTP Module to Prevent Deep Linking](http://www.irritatedvowel.com/Programming/DeepLinkingHttpModule.aspx)